# Setting up a webhosting at home with own domain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, email, dns-hosting, dyndns

**FIRST OFF ALL:** I understand that hosting sites from home is a terrible idea, but the point is that I have to test some sites with a very custom apache/php setup so I don't want to spend money renting some custom VPS servers because I have a domain name which isn't used and I have a decent internet connection.

**The idea:**
I want to set up a DNS server behind my router (+port forwards) and point my domains nameservers to my dns server behind my router. (the dynamic ip could be resolved with [Duck dns](https://www.duckdns.org/)).
After that i want to set up a few sub domains for apache and a mail server.

- Could this setup work or it is a completely bad idea?
- If it could work which DNS server is the good choice and how can I set up the DNS records for the mail and apache servers?

Comment: Yes it'll work.  You can also just edit the hosts file on your PC to do it as well.  Anyway, this is a bit off topic for serverfault.

Comment: SF doesn't really like this because it looks unprofessional. On http://superuser.com goes it better. This setup could work, any many people does that, especially new home sysadmin/developers in Hungary :-) But in your case I would use a remote proxy for outgoing mails (gmail is also okay for that) and for the dns (there are tons of free providers). And please don't forget: the ISP will periodically change your IP, you will have continously problems with that.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what's your problem but this is might going to be fix it. I was using freenom for free domain names (.tk,.cf etc.) and then, I was using Cloudflare as an proxy and an dns server to add every dns setting I had to use (A, AAAA, MX, etc.).